# How to use speech recognition functionality in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Generally, in Javascript, there is a way to using SpeechRecognition API. But in Salesforce this is under locker service. So is there any way to perform speech recognition in a lightning component?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the support for a given JavaScript API on the [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer). Unfortunately, searching for "SpeechRecognition" returns the following (source is **SecureWindow**):

| API | Support |
| --- | --- |
| webkitSpeechRecognition | **Not Supported** |
| webkitSpeechRecognitionError | **Not Supported** |
| webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent | **Not Supported** |